# Extract 1st value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My array is like: (Below is the dump extract)

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "0013" 
        [1]=> float(28.936563322435) 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "0003"
        [1]=> float(35.514521271921) 
    } 
    [2]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "0007" 
        [1]=> float(47.577230340278) 
    }
```

I would like to extract its 1st value like `0013` or `0007` etc into a variable say `$order` such that the final result is something like this

`$order= "0013,0003,0007";`

I tried to do something like this:

```
foreach($array as $x){
    $order = x[0].",";
    }
```

BUT it only extracts the first element

Comment: And what is your question? How to do so? Then please research this yourself. Otherwise it would be great if you showed previous attempts so we can help you for that specific problem

Comment: @kingkero I have added my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `array_map()` and `implode()`:

```
$order = implode(',', array_map(function($a) { return $a[0]; }, $array));
// string '0013,0003,0007' (length=14)
```

Or, if you're using PHP 5.5 or above:

```
$order = implode(',', array_column($array, 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you desire you can use

```
$order = implode(',', array_column($array, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $res[$i]=$array[$i][0];
}
$order=implode(",", $res);
```

This will give you a string with the first values of your nested arrays, all comma-separated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $arr[] = $v[0];
}
$order = implode(',', $arr);
```